# Wordpress Rest API custom endpoint optional param

Tags: api, rest-api, endpoints

Is it possible to use `register_rest_route()` with optional parameters in url?

Let's say route is registered this way:

```
register_rest_route( 'api', '/animals/(?P<id>\d+)', [
   'methods' => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
   'callback' => 'get_animals',
   'args' => [
        'id'
    ],
] );
```

It's now possible to perform api call on url like **/wp-json/api/animals/15**, but is there a way to declare the param as optional to also catch route like **/wp-json/api/animals/**.

I also tried declaring the route like below, but without success:

```
/animals/(?P<id>\d+)?
```

You can declare another route without the param or utilize GET params, but is there a way to do this already in the `register_rest_route()` ?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You should put the named parameters of the route regex into an optional capturing group:

```
register_rest_route( 'api', '/animals(?:/(?P<id>\d+))?', [
   'methods' => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
   'callback' => 'get_animals',
   'args' => [
        'id'
    ],
] );
```

The second parameter is simply a regex, thus you can use [normal regex logic](https://regex101.com/r/6iO5z0/1/) to make it more complex

Answer (score 5):

There may be a way to do it with one `register_rest_route` function call, I do not know how to do that and it *would* be ideal. However, duplicating the `register_rest_route` function call in the hooked method will do what you want.

```
register_rest_route( 'api', '/animals/', [
   'methods' => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
   'callback' => 'get_animals'
] );

register_rest_route( 'api', '/animals/(?P<id>\d+)', [
   'methods' => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
   'callback' => 'get_animals',
   'args' => [
        'id'
    ],
] );
```

It the get_animals method you'll want to have conditions that handle each case. One for if the `id` arg is set, and the fallback checks for `$_GET` variables.